# Could You Suggest Me Some Details of Realizing This LLM?

Tags: nlp, transformer, llm

I mean this hypothetical LLM:
https://twitter.com/RokoMijic/status/1663299142431432704

I'm trying to figure out how the neural network (let's abstract from the data) can be realized. I understand that:

1. It's a transformer;
2. It's sequence-to-sequence prediction (with a decoder, not with classification layers).

I'd like to ask more experienced ML people for more details of the realization. "Chronologically labelled data" means here concatenation of the events with the dates (like in life2vec)? Am I missing something else that is critical?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For the record, what makes this model very unlikely is that it's absolutely impossible to collect all the required input information, let alone to curate it. Many historical events are not documented at all or very poorly, and we don't know which ones really matter. So the model would be biased anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I thought of something very toy for the start:-). I understand  how giant the scope of the model as conceived by the author of the idea is (the difficulties having to be huge, too).

Answer (score 1):

Upon thinking it over, I came to a conclusion that *maybe* the dates can be omitted altogether; it's a strict chronological order of (the descriptions of) the events that will do the trick. I base this conjecture on the following words of the author of the idea:

> Training forces it to produce samples from day N having only seen sources from before day N.

So "chronological labeling" mentioned by the author will be implicit.